# Combine pow and log plot in same coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have troubles to plot two graphs in the same coordinate System. I can plot them individually but not put together:

```
\usetikzlibrary{
        calc,
        patterns,
        positioning
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
        samples=200,
        clip=false,
        my axis style/.style={
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis line style={
                ->,
            },
            legend style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            tick label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            xlabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            ylabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            xlabel=$X$,
            ylabel=$Y$
        },
    }
    \tikzset{
        >=stealth
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[my axis style,
  width=\textwidth,
  height=\textwidth,
    restrict x to domain=0:10,restrict y to domain=0:5,
    enlargelimits
      ]
    \addplot[domain=0:5,
    thick
    ] 
    {ln(20*x + 1)/ln(10)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[my axis style,
  width=\textwidth,
  height=\textwidth
  ]
    \addplot[domain=2.73:5,
    thick
    ] 
    {10^x -1 / 20};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

The representation should look like this at the end, but I must have missed something to make this work. Any other tips to draw tangent arrows are very welcome.

[image: Goal]

If both plots are in the same axis environment it yields:

```
\usetikzlibrary{
        calc,
        patterns,
        positioning
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
        samples=200,
        clip=false,
        my axis style/.style={
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis line style={
                ->,
            },
            legend style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            tick label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            xlabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            ylabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            xlabel=$X$,
            ylabel=$Y$
        },
    }
    \tikzset{
        >=stealth
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[my axis style,
  width=\textwidth,
  height=\textwidth,
  restrict x to domain=0:5, restrict y to domain=0:10^4,
    enlargelimits
      ]
    \addplot[domain=0:5,
    thick
    ] 
    {ln(20*x + 1)/ln(10)}; 
    \addplot[domain=2.73:5,
    thick
    ] 
    {10^x -1 / 20};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: First graph vanishes]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried to change the domains on which you draw both plots? On the domain [0,5], your power law takes a maximum value of nearly 10^5 whereas the maximum of the log is only about 2.

Comment: You can use multiple `\addplot` in the same `axis` environment.

Comment: I know that, but this does not yield the graph I need. One graph vanishes and the other appears to the right, I will try to change the domains...:-)

Comment: If I extend the domain, the second graph appears and the first vanishes. I would need to combine both graphs that live in different part in the coordination systems in the same domain

Comment: Can you show how one graph appears, and other one vanishes ?

Comment: I added the code and result in the question

Comment: This is more of a math problem in a way :) The two functions you've chosen differ in scale by four orders of magnitude in the given domain, so no wonder one of them looks flat.

Comment: But if I can plot them individually there must be a way to put them in the same graph by somehow disregard the differences in scale.

Comment: Why not just choose different functions? :) You obviously can't put them in the same axis as they are, simply because 10000 is not the same as 1. You could put two axes on top of each other though. I'll add an answer with a couple of options.

Comment: You are an absolute legend, thank you very much for your answer, this helps a lot. Just one more little question, how can I add labels beneath the x-axis just under the ycombs to label the derivatives and the intersection? I do not know where to place a node. Thanks

Comment: @janu7 Sorry, didn't see your comment. You need to write `@<username>` like I did here to ensure that other commenters are notified. Or comment on my answer instead, then I'd be notified. You can you try e.g. `xtick={2,4}, xticklabels={a,b}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just choose different functions, normalizing them is an easy way of making them scale the same. See first `tikzpicture` in the code below. I don't have any brilliant ideas with regard to the tangents, though searching may lead to previous questions about drawing tangents. That said, from the image you show you really want the tangents where the derivatives are equal for the two functions. So one option is to calculate the derivatives for the two functions find the x-value where they're equal, and determine the equation for the tangent lines passing through the points on the function. Having done that (with e.g. Wolfram alpha, or pen and paper), you can do `\addplot [samples at={x1, x2}, <->] {a*x + b};`, where x1 and x2 are values around the tangent point, and a,b are the values you determined previously.)

Another option is to make two axes, and place the second one on top of the first. See the second `tikzpicture` in the code below. You may want to adjust domains, axis limits etc, but you see the general idea I suppose.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
        samples=100,
        clip=false,
        my axis style/.style={
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            legend pos=outer north east,
            axis line style={
                ->,
            },
            legend style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            tick label style={
                font=\footnotesize
            },
            xlabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            ylabel style={
                at={
                    (ticklabel* cs:1)
                },
                anchor=west,
                font=\footnotesize,
            },
            xlabel=$X$,
            ylabel=$Y$
        },
    }
    \tikzset{
        >=stealth
    }
\begin{document}


First option: choose different functions, normalized at a useful x-value.

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    f(\x)=ln(2.2*\x + 1)/ln(10); % note different functions, which look more like the sketch
    g(\x)=2.2^\x -1;
    c(\x)=f(\x)/f(4.7); % normalize the functions so they are 1 at x=4.85
    u(\x)=g(\x)/g(4.7);
    }
]
  \begin{axis}[my axis style,
  width=0.5\textwidth,
  height=0.5\textwidth,
  domain=0:5,
  restrict y to domain=0:1.1,
  enlargelimits,
  xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
      ]
    \addplot[
    thick
    ] 
    {c(x)} node[right] {$c(X)$}; 
    \addplot[
    thick
    ] 
    {u(x)} node[above] {$u(X)$}; 
    
\addplot[ycomb,samples at={4.7}, very thin, gray] {c(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


Second option: two axes one on top of the other.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[my axis style,
  width=0.5\textwidth,
  height=0.5\textwidth,
  restrict y to domain=0:10^4,
  enlargelimits,
  name=ax1, % name first axis
  xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty % remove ticks 
      ]
   \addplot[domain=0:5,
    thick
    ] 
    {ln(20*x + 1)/ln(10)};  
\end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[my axis style,
  width=0.5\textwidth,
  height=0.5\textwidth,
  restrict y to domain=0:10^4,
  enlargelimits,
  % place the second axis with its origin ...
  anchor=origin,
  % at the origin of the first axis
  at={(ax1.origin)}, 
  % remove axis lines, ticks, etc.
  hide axis
      ]
   \addplot[domain=0:5,
   thick
   ] 
   {10^x -1 / 20};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```